# Ruby on Rails fails to connect to Mongodb locally using MongoMapper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, mongodb, mongomapper

I'm very new to rails and have been trying to experiment with using Mongodb on a web app.

I have been following this railscast tutorial [here](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/194-mongodb-and-mongomapper) word for word and have been running into issues with it not connecting to my local Mongodb.

I'm sure Mongodb is up and running since mongod shows up in my activity monitor and going to

```
http://localhost:28017/
```

shows:

```
http://imgur.com/KJ0JI.png
```

The problem is when I go to 0.0.0.0:3000/projects/new and try to add a new project name,
this comes up:

```
http://imgur.com/yxRwC.png
```

Here is my output when running script/server:

```
http://imgur.com/A9JTE.png
```

On my other apps, I have been using sqlite and haven't been having any issues. 
I tried uninstalling mongodb and running it anyways for testing purposes and I get
the exact some issue. I guess Mongodb simply isn't being detected through rails and MongoMapper.

Anyone have any idea how to fix this thing?
I spent many hours trying to fix this and resorted to getting a stackoverflow account
and asking on here.
Let me know if there's anything else anyone needs to possibly help diagnose the problem.
Any help would be appreciated.

note: sorry, since I'm new, I can't post pictures of the errors.
I hope you can take the time to view them on imgur

Comment: Do you have an intializer with connection parameters or anything like that in your code?

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the response.
I followed the railscast; so in:
/config/initializers/mongo_config.rb

I have:
MongoMapper.database = "todo-#{Rails.env}"  

Is there anything else I need in that file?

Comment: What do you get when running `mongo` (the mongo console) from the commandline? If it can connect, the problem is in your rails app. If it cannot, then there's something wrong with your mongo install.

Also, what platform are you on and what versions of MongoMapper, Rails, and mongodb are you using?

Comment: MongoDB shell version: 1.4.4
url: test
connecting to: test
type "help" for help

is what I get when I run mongo on the terminal after running mongod (the server).
So it seems like it can connect.

But i still don't know whats going on with the rails portion.
I sorta gave up on the situation and figured I would go back to it later and upgraded to rails 3rc and worked on another project.

After your response, I gave it another go, and followed this tutorial using mongoid.
http://wiki.github.com/fortuity/rails3-mongoid-devise/tutorial-walkthrough

Same problem. 

Still have the same issue.

Comment: Thanks for your reply btw.
running rails 3.0.0rc, mongodb 1.4.4, mongo_mapper 0.8.2